# Failed to seal APK, Visual Studio won't build apk

Tags: android, visual-studio, apk, keystore, android-keystore

Hei guys,

while trying to build an signed apk in my visual studio i ran in some errors:

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.284 secs

1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * What went wrong:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Execution failed for task ':packageRelease'.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : > Failed to seal APK
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * Try:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c ""C:\Users\poehler\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\DividendenApp\DividendenApp\platforms\android\gradlew.bat" cdvBuildRelease -b "C:\Users\poehler\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\DividendenApp\DividendenApp\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * What went wrong:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Execution failed for task ':packageRelease'.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : > Failed to seal APK
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * Try:
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
```

I created my keystore file like descriped in here: 
http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-package-publish-readme/

And i also edited my build.json like so:

```
{
     "android": {
        "release": {
            "alias": "myname",
            "keystore": "C:\\mykey.keystore",
            "keystoreType": "",
            "password": "key",
            "storePassword": "key"
        }
     }
 }
```

My ant.properties look like this:

```
key.store=C:\\mykey.keystore
key.alias=myname
key.store.password=key
key.alias.password=key
```

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution you just have to increase the key size **2048 to 4096**

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore c:\my-release-key.keystore -alias ABC -keyalg RSA -keysize 4096 -validity 100000
```

Comment: Mine was caused by `-keyalg RSA -keysize 4096 -validity 100000` being missing as I coped from MSDN and it's over 2 line (not word-wrapped) so it builds a keystore but it's not RSA or of correct size or validity,

Answer (score -1):

so I found an workaround with this issue.

Just go to the cordova directory and type

```
cordova build -release android
```

this one worked for me.

Comment: `'cordova' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Comment: are you in the right directory and do you have cordova installed properly on your system?

Comment: You should not install Cordova as well as the Visual Studios one if one updates and the other does not they might conflict as the installed one could take superiority of the VS one and do something VS does not know how to handle, also your answer makes no sense beacuse that command is what VS does if you watch the command console you will see it run `cordova build ....` and uses the same 2 config files, the `ant.properties` and `config.xml` and does not modify them in anyway.